# No Endpoint listening

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

> There was no endpoint listening at http://api/APIWCF.svc/soap that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

I've created a new website in IIS called API, I assigned it to the folder of where my application is. But when I run it, it gives me error mentioned above.

What I've tried:

- Deleted the website and re-added it in IIS.
- I set my project to run under local IIS under web properties.
- It's running under the current page.
- I changed the virtual directory.
- I checked the webconfig folder, which is as follows:

  ```
  <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  ```

Have I done something wrong in IIS?
I cant figure it out.

Comment: can you share the config of the service? the one in the question is from the client.

Comment: Also try changing endpoint address and remove the /soap from the url

Answer (score 0):

change the Url in the client endpoint to have the host name

```
<endpoint address="http://[your host name]api/APIWCF.svc" 
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_APIWCF"
            contract="Bettingworld.JuiceAPIWCF" 
            name="BasicHttpBinding_APIWCF"/>
</client>
```

Comment: api is my hostName

Comment: then remove the /soap. updating the answer

Comment: i tried it now,its still giving me the same error,should i move it to a different folder or something?

Comment: share your server side config

Comment: i added my web config file

Comment: i changed my local iis invisual studio and added the ip address,how ever now when i run the soap URL the no endpoint listening error is now replaced by 400 bad request error

Comment: can you click the app in ISS?

Comment: yeah i can click it, but my cache is returning null